# Looking for an Excel function

Tags: excel

Ok, so I have two columns of ID numbers.  Id like to have a function for column 3 below that looks at each cell in column 2 and return Y if it is in column 1 and N if it is not...

Example:

```
ID_Column1         ID_Column2                 Y/N
001                007                        N
002                002                        Y
003                004                        Y
004                010                        N
005
006
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the title is useless for any future inquiries and no original effort has been shown in what is a very basic question.

Comment: My apologies.  I do appreciate the help.  This forum should be for those who are learning as well as experts.

Answer (score 1):

In C2:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B2,A:A,0)),"Y","N")
```

OR

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,B2),"Y","N")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe the function you are looking for is:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,A:A,0)),"N","Y")
```

Explanation:  This formula will attempt to find the index of B2 in column A.  If it does not find the value, match will throw an error.  If it does find the value, it will return a number.  The IsError function then checks this match function and returns a true or a false.  So if match can't find a value, match returns error, then iserror returns true.  The if statement will look at the result of the iserror function and will assing an "N" if the match was an error (IE Not found), and a "Y" if there was no error (IE value was found).

Match Function:  This will look for the first parameter (B2), in the second parameter (any range, I used the whole 'A' Column), and the third parameter specifies what type of match to perform.  "0" performs an exact match (IE there will be an error when searching 007.  "1" looks for the value that is closest to the search item without going over it (IE 007 would return 006).  Note that data must be sorted in ascending order to use "1".  A value of "-1" is the greater than version, and data must be sorted in reverse order.

IsError Function:  This returns a true if the expression it evaluates returns an error.  So, if you search 007, Match will throw an error, therefore IsError will return true.  If you search 002, it will find a match, so match will return the position of 002 in the array, which is not an error.  IsError will return false.

If Function:  If will evaluate the first parameter, called the expression, and if it evaluates to TRUE, it will return the second parameter, and if it is false, it will return the third parameter.

Please ignore the people that are so hostile on this forum.  While SO may be a more technical forum than you are accustomed to, that is not a reason why you should feel intimidated asking a question.  This is actually a pretty common question and not one that is readily apparent on how to solve.  I see no reason to close your question or chastise you for asking it.  Have a great day!